# Translation of "take your time"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

In English, when making a polite request, it's common to say "take your time" (to tell the other person there's no need to rush). What is the most natural translation of this into Spanish? Is this phrase as common in Spanish as in English, or are there other ways to express the same thought (telling someone not to rush and worry about something you've requested of them)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost literal, and natural, is:

> Tómate tu tiempo  (or, with 'usted' treatment: "Tómese su tiempo")

Even more natural, for me (I'm from Argentina) :

> "No hay apuro"
>
> "Sin apuro"
>
> (no need to hurry)

Comment: In Spain "No hay prisa" is widely used too.

Comment: Or "Sin prisas"

Comment: Would *Tómate **el** tiempo.* work too?

Comment: @jrdioko: Yes, but 'tu tiempo' is more usual, in my experience.

Comment: @jrdioko: It works if the listener completes the sentence: _Tómate el tiempo [que necesites] / [necesario]_